# NavigationDrawer - programmatically created submenu disappears after screen rotate

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a problem with dynamically (programmatically) created submenu in navigation drawer when rotating the menu. My navigation view menu xml contains only main menu (see below). Submenu is added when onCreate event is called. Everything works fine until I rotate the screen - the only displayed thing from a submenu is its label. I tried to investigate the problem and also tried with static variables, but with no success.

Can you tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
     <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single" android:id="@+id/main_group">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/leagues_in_progress_item"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_format_line_spacing_black_48dp"
                android:title="@string/title_activity_leagues_in_progress" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/last_matches_item"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_access_alarm_black_48dp"
                android:title="@string/title_activity_last_matches" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/archive_item"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_folder_open_black_48dp"
                android:title="@string/title_activity_archive" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/put_score_item"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_circle_outline_black_48dp"
                android:title="@string/title_activity_put_score" />
        </group>
    </menu>
```

HomeActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pinokio);

    this.mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.pinokioLayout);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    this.mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, this.mDrawerLayout, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);
    this.mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(this.mDrawerToggle);

    HomeActivity.mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    this.addLeaguesSubmenu();
    HomeActivity.mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    displayMenuFragment(menuItem);
                    return true;
                }
            });


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        this.displayMenuFragment(HomeActivity.mNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0));
    }
}

/**
 * Add submenu that contains leagues in progress
 * @return HomeActivity
 */
private void addLeaguesSubmenu()
{
    if (this.internetConnection.isOnline()) {
        if (HomeActivity.menuLeagues == null) {
            Intent intent = this.getIntent();
            HomeActivity.menuLeagues = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("leagues");
        }
        this.leaguesSubmenu.generate(HomeActivity.mNavigationView, HomeActivity.menuLeagues);
    }
}
```

And that's the method generating a submenu:

```
@Override
public void generate(NavigationView navigationView, ArrayList<League> leagues)
{
    Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
    SubMenu leaguesSubMenu = menu.addSubMenu(this.context.getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_leagues_in_progress));
    League league;
    MenuItem menuItem;

    for (int i = 0; i<leagues.size(); i++) {
        league = leagues.get(i);
        menuItem = leaguesSubMenu.add(league.getShortName());

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("leagueId", league.getId());
        menuItem.setIntent(intent);

        if (!league.getFoosballMode()) {
            menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_fifa);
        }
        else {
            menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_foosball);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is probably because when rotated the View gets reinflated but your generation code is in onCreate, so you have two options if thats the case. You can re-generate the menu when the view gets reinflated or add this to your Activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Also if your interesting refer to here for information on handling configuration changes such as rotation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html